# Why is this C++11 code containing rand() slower with multiple threads than with one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11

I'm trying around on the new C++11 threads, but my simple test has abysmal multicore performance. As a simple example, this program adds up some squared random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

double add_single(int N) {
    double sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        sum+= sqrt(1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);
    }
    return sum/N;
}

void add_multi(int N, double& result) {
    double sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        sum+= sqrt(1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);
    }
    result = sum/N;
}

int main() {
    srand (time(NULL));
    int N = 1000000;

    // single-threaded
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double result1 = add_single(N);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "time single: " << time_elapsed << std::endl;

    // multi-threaded
    std::vector<std::thread> th;
    int nr_threads = 3;
    double partual_results[] = {0,0,0};
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_threads; ++i) 
        th.push_back(std::thread(add_multi, N/nr_threads, std::ref(partual_results[i]) ));
    for(auto &a : th)
        a.join();
    double result_multicore = 0;
    for(double result:partual_results)
        result_multicore += result;
    result_multicore /= nr_threads;
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "time multi: " << time_elapsed << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with 'g++ -std=c++11 -pthread test.cpp' on Linux and a 3core machine, a typical result is

```
time single: 33
time multi: 565
```

So the multi threaded version is more than an order of magnitude slower. I've used random numbers and a sqrt to make the example less trivial and prone to compiler optimizations, so I'm out of ideas.

**edit**:

1. This problem scales for larger N, so the problem is not the short runtime
2. The time for creating the threads is not the problem. Excluding it does not change the result significantly

Wow I found the problem. It was indeed rand(). I replaced it with an C++11 equivalent and now the runtime scales perfectly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can't reproduce. What optimization level are you using?

Comment: You're measuring algorithm + **time of creating threads which is slow due to system calls**. Move the timer after creation of threads and then run threads.

Comment: `rand()` is not a multi-tread safe function generally. Use `rand_r()`.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I was able to replicate using gcc 4.7.2 and `O3`

Comment: +1 for well-composed question.  Nice sscce and compiler instructions appreciated.

Comment: To expand on @MM.'s comment: 500ms is not significant enough to be relevant, the thread creation time is much more than your algorithm's running time. Run it with a much higher `N` (eg. `N = 1000000000`) and give us the results. ;)

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Better still, use C++11 random engines like `std::minstd_rand`.

Comment: He is measuring how different the behemoth from VW? Why this is upvoted too slow?

Comment: looks like false sharing/cache invalidation with the rand() function.

Comment: Are there any guaranteed memory barriers on `now`?  Ie, in theory the compiler is free to move thing from one side of `now` to another, right?

Comment: @mikeseymour you are right. I am not sure if rand_s is a standard C++ function, i merely did old school man rand(2) in my emacs before commenting.

Comment: On Windows though, IIRC, they store the state of rand, strtok, etc.. in thread-specific storage, so these functions are actually thread-safe there (provided MS implementation of the standard C library is used).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: According to my manpage, `rand_r` is an obsolete POSIX function. It's not part of the C or C++ standard.

Answer (score 27):

On my system the behavior is same, but as Maxim mentioned, rand is not thread safe. When I change rand to rand_r, then the multi threaded code is faster as expected.

```
void add_multi(int N, double& result) {
double sum=0;
unsigned int seed = time(NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    sum+= sqrt(1.0*rand_r(&seed)/RAND_MAX);
}
result = sum/N;
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the issue is actually that `rand` **is** thread-safe, and there is a great deal of lock contention when multiple threads are all calling `rand`. With `rand_r` each call has its own data, so there is no contention.

Comment: @PeteBecker I also thought like you, but `rand` man page states `The function rand() is not reentrant or thread-safe, since it uses hidden state that is modified on each call.`

Comment: @Étienne - using hidden state means it's not re-entrant. It does not mean that it's not thread-safe. If changing `rand` to `rand_r` makes it much faster, that pretty much establishes that `rand` is synchronizing its internal state.

Comment: "**The function rand() is not** reentrant or **thread-safe**" doesn't mean rand is not thread-safe?

Comment: @PeteBecker It's *possible* that your particular implementation of `rand` chooses to be thread-safe (as evidenced by the timing data).  But if the documentation explicitly says it's not thread-safe, then relying on that is a Bad Idea -- future versions would be free to change without warning and break your code in very-difficult-to-debug ways.

Comment: @EdwardLoper - the question wasn't about whether `rand` is thread-safe. It was about why the code is so slow, and that's answered by the obvious locking in `rand`, regardless of what a man page somewhere might say. As they say in the Army, if the map doesn't match the terrain, trust the terrain.

Answer (score 22):

As you discovered, [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) is the culprit here.

For those who are curious, it's possible that this behavior comes from your implementation of `rand` using a mutex for thread safety.

For example, [eglibc](http://www.eglibc.org/) defines `rand` in terms of `__random`, which [is defined as](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/libc/stdlib/random.c?view=markup):

```
long int
__random ()
{
  int32_t retval;

  __libc_lock_lock (lock);

  (void) __random_r (&unsafe_state, &retval);

  __libc_lock_unlock (lock);

  return retval;
}
```

This kind of locking would force multiple threads to run serially, resulting in lower performance.

Answer (score 8):

The time needed to execute the program is very small (33msec). This means that the overhead to create and handle several threads may be more than the real benefit. Try using programs that need longer times for the execution (e.g., 10 sec).

Comment: he's only creating 3 threads. It doesn't explain the 565ms. And I can't reproduce the results on VS2012 so i suspect something else is wrong here.

Comment: As stated in the edit, the problem scales. Same or comparable result with much higher N's

Comment: On my Linux system with g++ 4.7 and -O3 I had comparable results.

Comment: This is a suggestion and does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

To make this faster, use a thread pool pattern.

This will let you enqueue tasks in other threads without the overhead of creating a `std::thread` each time you want to use more than one thread.

Don't count the overhead of setting up the queue in your performance metrics, just the time to enqueue and extract the results.

Create a set of threads and a queue of tasks (a structure containing a `std::function<void()>`) to feed them.  The threads wait on the queue for new tasks to do, do them, then wait on new tasks.

The tasks are responsible for communicating their "done-ness" back to the calling context, such as via a `std::future<>`.  The code that lets you enqueue functions into the task queue might do this wrapping for you, ie this signature:

```
template<typename R=void>
std::future<R> enqueue( std::function<R()> f ) {
  std::packaged_task<R()> task(f);
  std::future<R> retval = task.get_future();
  this->add_to_queue( std::move( task ) ); // if we had move semantics, could be easier
  return retval;
}
```

which turns a naked `std::function` returning `R` into a nullary `packaged_task`, then adds that to the tasks queue.  Note that the tasks queue needs be move-aware, because `packaged_task` is move-only.

Note 1: I am not all that familiar with `std::future`, so the above could be in error.

Note 2: If tasks put into the above described queue are dependent on each other for intermediate results, the queue could deadlock, because no provision to "reclaim" threads that are blocked and execute new code is described.  However, "naked computation" non-blocking tasks should work fine with the above model.

Comment: You could replace your `shared_ptr<promise<R>>` and lambda expression with `packaged_task<R()>`, it would make `enqueue` **much** simpler

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think that did it.