# MPI with pthreads slow performance

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, mpi

I'm working on a program that uses Monte Carlo method to estimate the value of pi, using MPI (MPICH) and pthreads. The problem is, the version using only MPI is much faster than the version using both MPI and pthreads. I did use `MPI_Init_thread` to initialize, like this:

```
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided);
```

And after the call provided has value 1, which is MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, so threading is supported.

This is the timeline of when the nodes finish the computation, when using the version with both MPI and pthreads:

```
4.867465s
6.534831s
11.053412s
11.324309s
11.417703s
11.607459s
11.730345s
11.820486s
11.845832s
11.903317s
12.065178s
12.078911s
12.081720s
12.209571s
12.363889s
12.437287s
12.686957s
13.262722s
```

And this is the timeline of when the nodes finish the computation when using the version with MPI only:

```
0.862212s
0.863246s
0.863321s
0.863349s
0.863310s
0.863730s
0.863844s
0.863877s
0.863860s
0.863858s
0.864253s
0.866158s
0.867301s
0.869959s
0.872734s
0.874739s
0.896928s
0.968937s
```

It almost seems like the version with MPI and pthreads was running serially.

Comment below if there is anything else you need to know! Thanks everyone in advance.

EDITED:

I ran my code using:

```
mpiexec -f hosts -n 18 ./pthread_pi 1000000000 4
```

with hosts being the file containing the nodes' addresses, 18 is the number of nodes, and 1000000000 is the number of times to run the simulations for the Monte Carlo method, and 4 is the number of threads to spawn. All the nodes that I ran the program on have 4 cores.

I measured my time from the point when I finish all initialization and start doing the simulations for pi, to the point when I finish doing the simulations. That is also the only part using pthreads. Inside that part, I divide the work into 4, and spawn 4 threads to do the simulation.

EDITED 2:

Based on @Gilles's comment, I tried running with this command:

```
mpiexec -f hosts -n 18 -bind-to none ./pthread_pi 1000000000 4
```

This is my thread worker function, which is used to run the simulation and to be called by pthread_create():

```
void *thread_worker(void *data)
{
    thread_data_t *tdata = (thread_data_t *) data;
    long work = tdata->work;
    long i, counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < work; i++) {
        double x = double_rand(0, radius * 2);
        double y = double_rand(0, radius * 2);
        double dist = square_distance(x, y);

        if (dist <= radius * radius)
            counter += 1;
    }

    pthread_exit((void *) counter);
}
```

As you can see, there is no synchronization involved. And this is the function to measure time:

```
double get_time()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    double retval;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    retval = tv.tv_sec;
    retval += tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0;
    return retval;
}
```

EDITED 3:

This is the code for double_rand():

```
double double_rand(double d_min, double d_max)
{
    double ret = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return d_min + ret * (d_max - d_min);
}
```

Comment: How do you launch your code? Do you have one core per thread within each of your MPI processes? Did you pay attention to MPI process-to-core affinity (aka pinning)? How did you measure your time?

Comment: @Gilles I added some information above. However, I have no idea what MPI process-to-core affinity is.

Comment: 3 things that I can imagine going wrong: 1/ your pthread code is just wrong, with many synchronizations etc; 2/ you're measuring cpu time instead of elapsed time; and 3/ your MPI implementation does process-to-core binding without you knowing, forcing your threads to share the same core instead of spreading (see [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tuning#using-paffinity-v1.4) or [here](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Process-core_Binding) for example). Could also be a mixture of all that... Time for a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Gilles I added some code and explanation above.

Comment: Is your `double_rand()` function thread safe? Couldn't it introduce race conditions and/or serializations?

Comment: @Gilles That's a good question. I'm not sure, but the estimation of pi at the end is still quite accurate. I posted the code for double_rand() above.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16716005/5239503) and I think you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Gilles That solved the problem. Thank you!